# How to obtain parent child relationship in EXPRESSJS/MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I have table like this:

- no
- alphabets

**no** table contains (1,2,3,4)

**alphabets** table contains (apple,ball,cat,dog)

This my js file:

```
var connection = require('../connection');

function Todo() {
    this.get = function(res) {
        connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
            con.query('select * from no', function(err, result) {
                for(var key in result) {
                    var no = result[key].number;
                    console.log(no); 
                    con.query('select * from alphabets', function(err, result2) {
                        for(var key in result2) {
                            var alph = result2[key].alphabets;
                            console.log(no+"."+alph);
                        }
                        console.log('\n');
                        });
                    }
                    con.release();
                    res.send(result);
                });
            });
        };
    }
module.exports = new Todo();
```

I need to have the parent child relationship between the two queries no table as parent and alphabets as child.

My Expected Output at command prompt :

```
    1.apple
    1.ball
    1.cat
    1.dog

    2.apple
    2.ball
    2.cat
    2.dog

    3.apple
    3.ball
    3.cat
    3.dog

    4.apple
    4.ball
    4.cat
    4.dog
```

Output I got:

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    4.apple
    4.ball
    4.cat
    4.dog


    4.apple
    4.ball
    4.cat
    4.dog


    4.apple
    4.ball
    4.cat
    4.dog


    4.apple
    4.ball
    4.cat
    4.dog
```

I'm wondering that why the first query runs asynchronously and completes it loop. How can I create a relationship between the two queries so queries run synchronously avoiding last value of no table to be repeated at alphabets table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run functions with callbacks synchronously using [SynJS](https://github.com/amaksr/SynJS). I refactored your code a bit, and here is a working version:

```
global.SynJS = global.SynJS || require('synjs');
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    database : 'tracker',
    user     : 'tracker',
    password : 'tracker123'
});


var myFunction1=function( mysql, connection ) {

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        SynJS.resume(_synjsContext);
    });
    SynJS.wait();


    var result;
    connection.query('select * from no', function(err, res) {
        result = res;
        SynJS.resume(_synjsContext);
    });
    SynJS.wait();

    for(var key in result)
    {
        var no = result[key].number;
        console.log(no);
        var result2=null;
        connection.query('select * from alphabets', function(err, res2) {
            result2 = res2;
            SynJS.resume(_synjsContext);
        });
        SynJS.wait();

        for(var key in result2)
        {
            var alph = result2[key].alphabets;
            console.log(no+"."+alph);
        }
        console.log('\n');

    }
};

SynJS.run(myFunction1,null, mysql, connection, function (ret) {
    console.log('done');
});
```